# How to create SpatialLine objects from a list?

Tags: list, for-loop, spatial, r-sp

I'm trying to build a SpatialLines object from a list that contains 124 segments. 
Each segment in the list contains the x,y coordinates for each node (see below). I'm using the following code to create the SpatialLines object, but it just retrieves one segment. Any suggestions?

```
test.func = function(x){
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    tt[[i]] <- x[i]; tt[[i]]  = Line(tt[[i]]); tt[[i]]  = Lines(list(tt[[i]] ), 'i')
    tt1 = SpatialLines(list(tt[[i]]))
} 
return(tt1)}
```

Many thanks

Ash,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem resides in the 'i' argument in Lines, which should be modified to as.character (i).
The first one is giving the 2nd argument to Lines( , ) as 'i' each time through the loop ('i', 'i', ...) whereas using as.character (i) is giving the 2nd argument as ("1", "2", ... ).

Thanks to Eric Berger for the advice and the help.

```
test.func = function(x){
tt1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    tt1[[i]] <- x[[i]];
    tt1[[i]]  = Line(tt1[[i]]);
    tt1[[i]]  = Lines(list(tt1[[i]] ), as.character(i))
}
tt2 = SpatialLines(tt1)   
return(tt2)
```

}